# What is the meaning of the domination between two random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have just read that: the random variable $Exp(1)$ dominates the $Uniform[0,1]$, and denote $Exp(1) \succ Uniform[0,1]$.
I've never heard or seen this definition before. Is it related to $\mathbb{P}(X > Y)$ where $X \sim Exp(1)$ and $Y \sim Uniform[0,1]$ are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is referring to [first-order stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#First-order).

Here $P(X \ge x) = e^{-x}$ is larger than $P(Y \ge x) = 1-x$ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Oh thank you a lot.